# "expected primary-expression before" error when passing pointer to function

Tags: c++, typedef

I'm currently working on code which utilizes an external library and here is part of what is given in the library:

```
typedef void (*func_start_t) (void *);
extern int create(func_start_t func, void *a);
```

I'm trying to call this with the following line of code (where foo is another function):

```
create(func_start_t foo, *args);
```

However I keep getting an erro `expected primary-expression before foo`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something wrong. The `func_start_t` in the call to the function is totally unnecessary (and incorrect). You should just write:

```
create(foo, *args); //Assuming `args` is a pointer to a pointer
```

Comment: My method foo is defined as `void foo(void *args)` and args is defined as char *args[].  However, I keep getting an error "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Comment: @Nosrettap: The "symbol(s) not found" error is not related to the problem in the question. It means that the linker cannot find the definition for a particular symbol (I am guessing it is the `create` function in this case, but the error message should say which symbol it actually is). This happens if you do not supply the linker with all the libraries and object files that your program depends on.

Answer (score 0):

Just call this:

```
create(foo, *args);
```

I'm assuming `foo` is a function defined as:

```
void foo(void*) {/*....*/}
```

Comment: Can I not have foo be defined where the parameter is something other than void *.  Say void foo(char *)?  Can I not do implicit casting like this?